# Event after back button pressed

Tags: xamarin, event-handling, xamarin.forms

I can't find any event that could be fired when page **shown** after back button is pressed on another page.
OnAppearing isn't fired. Page constructor also.
In UWP there exist OnNavigated event..

Comment: @Option JavaScript and Xamarin... That's not the same question

Comment: Xamarin can use Javascript if I'm not mistaken?

Comment: Can't. Only C# and F#

Comment: In the event this assists: https://xamarinhelp.com/xamarin-forms-webview-executing-javascript/ seems very much so that you can

Comment: WebView is a control that could be used in Xamarin

Comment: As Alexej Sommer said, it's not related.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each `Page` has an override for `OnBackButtonPressed`.

```
protected override bool OnBackButtonPressed()
{
   return base.OnBackButtonPressed();
}
```

If you want to perform an action on the page you should look at the `OnAppearing` and `OnDisappearing` overrides on the page. If that doesn't suit your needs you could you could look into using the [MessagingCenter](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/messaging-center/) to trigger an event on the appropriate method and subscribing to it in the screen you're navigating to.

As far as I know there are no other events that can handle this situation. What platform are you on? `OnAppearing` should be called but Android has some different behavior where it isn't called e.g. in some pop modal situations. To diagnose further you should provide some sample code on how you're pushing/popping pages etc.

Comment: No, no. I want to find event when page is shown. Not when button pressed

Comment: The only event that handles that is the `OnAppearing` which you can override on the page. Make sure you override on the page that you're navigating to.

Comment: Yes, I am overriding it. And it is not fired when I move to another page after clicking back button will return back

Comment: Is `OnDisappearing` called on the page that is moving out of view? Also there is a difference between the hardware back button and the software back button. E.g. on Android the `OnBackButtonPressed` is only called when the hardware back button is pressed.

Comment: I'm not quite sure why this is being downvoted? It suggests the exact same thing that the original poster posted as the solution :-/

Comment: Seems that by some my fault I have unsubscribed from OnAppearing.

Comment: OnAppearing does not work in Android when navigating back to the page